# AngularJS: weird controller call with module organization

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

I've made a module code structure, here is my index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>

        <!-- AngularJS -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-beta.18/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.18/angular-route.min.js"></script>

        <!-- Lazy loading module -->
        <script src="assets/libs/ocLazyLoading.min.js"></script>

        <!-- App -->
        <script src="app/app.js"></script>
        <script src="app/config.js"></script>

        <script src="app/article/article.js"></script>

        <base href="http://localhost/angularjs-blog/">

    </head>

    <body data-ng-app="Blog">

        <div data-ng-view></div>

    </body>
</html>
```

**app.js:**

```
var app = {};

app.main = angular.module('Blog', [
    // Tools
    'ngRoute',
    'oc.lazyLoad',

    // Modules
    'Blog.Article'
]);
```

**config.js:**

```
app.main.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {

    $routeProvider.otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
    });

}]);
```

**article.js:**

```
app.article = angular.module('Blog.Article', ['ngRoute', 'oc.lazyLoad']);

app.article.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {

    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'app/article/views/articles.html',
            controller: 'ArticlesController',
            resolve: {
                lazy: ['$ocLazyLoad', function($ocLazyLoad) {
                    return $ocLazyLoad.load({
                        name: 'Blog',
                        files: [
                            'app/article/controllers/articles.controller.js',
                            'app/article/article.service.js',
                            'common/directives/button.directive.js'
                        ]
                    });
                }]
            }
        })
        .when('/article/:id', {
            templateUrl: 'app/article/views/article.html',
            controller: 'ArticleController',
            resolve: {
                lazy: ['$ocLazyLoad', function($ocLazyLoad) {
                    return $ocLazyLoad.load({
                        name: 'Blog',
                        files: [
                            'app/article/controllers/article.controller.js',
                            'app/article/article.service.js'
                        ]
                    });
                }]
            }

        });

}]);
```

**article.controller.js:**

```
// Controller
app.article.controller('ArticleController', ['$scope', 'ArticleService', function ($scope, ArticleService) {


}]);
```

This is the problem, I can't write `app.article.controller` as my router does not find "ArticleController". I have to write `app.main.controller` instead. And it seems weird for me. I've created an object property for this module, and I don't want to see the controller in the `main` property, right?

I really don't understand what's going on. I'm using AngularJS version 1.3.0-beta.18.

**ANSWER**: As I my button.directive.js was in `app.main`, the right routing is:

```
app.article = angular.module('Blog.Article', ['ngRoute', 'oc.lazyLoad']);

app.article.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {

    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'app/article/views/articles.html',
            controller: 'ArticlesController',
            resolve: {
                lazy: ['$ocLazyLoad', function($ocLazyLoad) {
                    return $ocLazyLoad.load([{
                        name: 'Blog',
                        files: ['common/directives/button.directive.js']
                    }, {
                        name: 'Blog.Article',
                        files: [
                            'app/article/controllers/articles.controller.js',
                            'app/article/article.service.js'
                        ]
                    }]);
                }]
            }
        })
        .when('/article/:id', {
            templateUrl: 'app/article/views/article.html',
            controller: 'ArticleController',
            resolve: {
                lazy: ['$ocLazyLoad', function($ocLazyLoad) {
                    return $ocLazyLoad.load({
                        name: 'Blog.Article',
                        files: [
                            'app/article/controllers/article.controller.js',
                            'app/article/article.service.js'
                        ]
                    });
                }]
            }

        });

}]);
```

Comment: It's unclear to me why you have two modules, `app.main` and `app.article`, and `app.main` loads `app.article` as a dependency? It would be so much simpler if you put everything under one module.

Comment: Because there is a main "app" with modules as dependencies (here just one). I'm trying to reproduce this behavior: https://github.com/sgebhardt/ng-module-boilerplate

Comment: @sylouuu are you sure ocLazyLoad works well with `$routeProvider`? I believe the problem is that the _article.controller.js_ script is not being loaded in time, that's why angular can't find the "ArticlesController" on the 'Blog.Article' module. Try adding `<script src="app/article/controllers/article.controller.js"></script>` to the HTML and see if it works.

Comment: I'm sure it works without a module organization, I checked.

Comment: In that case I keep my question: Are you sure ocLazyLoad works well with `$routeProvider`? All their examples are with [ui-route](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) and not `ngRoute`...

Comment: Yeah look at this: https://github.com/ocombe/ocLazyLoad/issues/53

Comment: Try changing `name: 'Blog'` to `name: 'Blog.Article'` in the _article.js_ file.

Comment: I tried but files are not loaded, I can't see my directive.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59592/discussion-between-bmleite-and-sylouuu).

Answer (score 1):

from documentation

**controller** – {(string|function()=} – Controller fn that should be associated with newly created scope or the *name of a registered controller if passed as a string.*

when you are writing `ArticleController` angular don't know in which namespace to look, because your controller stored in other module   therefore you must provide the right reference (namespace) for your controller

**UPDATE 1:**
the problem was that what you embedded the angular lib after body and your script (jsffidlle script) worked before angular had been attached let me update example

[This is an updated example](http://jsfiddle.net/3pgjy58g/12/)

Comment: I tried but didn't find the right syntax to call the namespaced controller.

Comment: app.article.ArticleController

Comment: As a string I got an error: https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ng/areq?p0=app.article.ArticleController&p1=not%20aNaNunction,%20got%20undefined

Comment: Blog.Article.ArticleController

Comment: Same result, I don't understand.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59590/discussion-between-sylouuu-and-narek-mamikonyan).